# Как в pandas установить текстовый формат для всей колонки?

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет! Использую Pandas для записи данных в excel файл. Данные добавляются в числовом формате, не знаю почему. И в некоторых ячейках есть апостроф(см.скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если изменить формат ячейки с числового на текстовый то все пропадает. И мне нужно это сделать. Только как?

Данные приходят из другого файла(см.скри)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def get_list_data(input_file_name):
    '''Получение списка товаров из файла'''
    list_data = []
    xl = pd.read_excel(input_file_name,sheet_name=0)
    for item in xl.to_dict(orient='record'):
        list_data.append(item)

    return list_data

def expand_in_file(file_input):
    list_items = get_list_data(file_input)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_items)
    # df.astype({'Артикул':'string'}).dtypes
    # print(df)
    # df['Артикул'] = df['Артикул'].astype(str)
    # print(df['Артикул'])
    # df = df.astype(str)
    df.apply(str)
    df.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=False,header=None)
```

Из функции `get_list_data` возвращается список из словарей.
И мне нужно изменить формат у первого столбца, на текстовый формат.
В коде можете увидеть мои попытки изменить формат, но они все почему-о формат не изменяли, то есть апостроф оставался

P.S. В настоящий момент столбец `Артикул` имеет тип `object`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так вы проверяйте, изменился ли формат, с помощью df.info(). А наличие в ячейке апострофа - показатель, что она имеет строковый тип.

Comment: А как тогда избавится от апострофа? Я проверял через `dtypes`

Comment: в датафрейме при печати его содержимого в ячейке тоже есть апостроф?

Comment: @strawdog В самой ячейки нету, и в словаре тоже нету

Comment: @strawdog Когда изменяю формат на Текстовый, то апостроф пропадает

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/806771/why-would-all-text-columns-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-begin-with-a-leading-single-q#:~:text=The%20apostrophe%20'%20is%20a%20special,Selecting%20the%20cells

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое